# Is there any way to find out number of cloudlet on a specific VM in cloudsim?

Tags: cloud, simulation, cloudsim

Is there any way to find out number of cloudlet on VM in cloudsim?

Answer (score 1):

There's a method `getVmId()` of  `Class Cloudlet` which gives you the ID of VM on which `cloudlet` would be scheduled.

```
cloudlet.getVmId()
```

Returns:
VM Id or  -1 if the Cloudlet was not assigned to a VM

By setting counter you can count number of cloudlets running on particular VM.

Comment: Thank you very much